# Передать значение с button в input. Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка вызывающая модальное окно. В окне есть форма в которой спрятан input.
Задача: отправить значения атрибута value с кнопки вызова модального окна в спрятанный input.
У меня почему-то возвращает value='undefined'.
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
Заранее спасибо.

```js
let modal = document.getElementById('modalForm');

let openModalBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('openModalBtn');

let setAttrInput = document.querySelector('input[type=hidden]');

let close = document.getElementsByClassName('closeModal')[0];

for (let i = 0; i < openModalBtn.length; i++) {
    openModalBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        openModalWindow();
    })
}

close.addEventListener('click', function() {
    closeModalWindow();
});

function openModalWindow() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    if (openModalBtn.value === '') {
        setAttrInput.setAttribute('value','');
    }
    setAttrInput.value = openModalBtn.value;
    console.log(setAttrInput);
}

function closeModalWindow() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button class="openModalBtn" value="value-1">
  Перезвоните мне
</button>

<div id="modalForm" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>Text</h3>
      <span class="closeModal">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>text</p>
      <form id="callbackForm" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text">
        <button type="submit" value="test text"></button>
        <input type="hidden" id="test1" name="fromDate" value="">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы проверяете нажаты ли кнопки через перебор элементов `[i]` а хотите вывести только значение. 
Для этого можно передать значение в функцию. 
Пример(Обратите внимание на комментарии):

```js
    let modal = document.getElementById('modalForm');

    let openModalBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('openModalBtn');

    let setAttrInput = document.querySelector('input[type=hidden]');

    let close = document.getElementsByClassName('closeModal')[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < openModalBtn.length; i++) {
        openModalBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            let val = openModalBtn[i].value; // Получаем value нажатой кнопки
            openModalWindow(val); // Передаём её в функцию
        })
    }

    close.addEventListener('click', function() {
        closeModalWindow();
    });

    function openModalWindow(val) { // В функции значение из нажатой кнопки
        modal.style.display = "block";
        if (openModalBtn.value === '') {
            setAttrInput.setAttribute('value','');
        }
        setAttrInput.value = val; // Добавляем это значение
        console.log(setAttrInput);
    }

    function closeModalWindow() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```html
<button class="openModalBtn" value="value-1">
    Перезвоните мне
</button>

<div id="modalForm" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Text</h3>
            <span class="closeModal">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>text</p>
            <form id="callbackForm" action="" method="post">
                <input type="text">
                <button type="submit" value="test text"></button>
                <input type="hidden" id="test1" name="fromDate" value="">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Denis640Kb - большое СПАСИБО!